# For a CRV, X, if the pdf is given, can you find the pdf of a Y?

Tags: random-variables

If the pdf of a continuous random variable, $X$, is defined such that:

$$ f_{X}(x)= \frac{3}{(1+x)^{4}}, x\geqslant0 $$

And a random variable, $Y$, is defined as:

$$ Y=\frac{1}{X} $$

What is the method of finding the pdf of $Y$?

From what I've cobbled together (and I could be wrong), I need to get the *cdf* of X and also calculate $P(Y\geqslant y)$ to get the *pdf* of Y?

I'm not looking for the solution but rather the procedure. Happy to be directed towards any resources!

**edit 1**

With some confidence thanks to *Michael*, I went ahead to get a *cdf* of *X*, evaluated over the limits from $0$ to *x*:

$$ F_X(x) = 1-\frac{1}{(1+x)^3} $$

And I have an expression for $P(Y\geqslant y) = P(X\leqslant y^{-1})$.

Am I on the right track?

**edit 2**

Continuing:

$$ F_X(y^{-1}) 
= 1-\frac{1}{(1+\frac{1}{y})^3} 
= 1-\frac{y^3}{(y+1)^3}
$$

And since $F_Y(y) = \int f_Y(y)$, we take the derivative of $F_Y(y)$ to get the *pdf*.

$$
f_Y(y) = -\frac{3y^2}{(y+1)^4}
$$

Defined over $1 \geqslant y > 0$.

Does that seem correct?

Comment: That is a good procedure.  Can you give an expression for $P[Y>y]$ in terms of something about $X$?

Comment: So if I've got it correctly, $P(Y>y) \rightarrow P(\frac{1}{X} >y) \rightarrow P(X< \frac{1}{y})$ would be the progression of my expression?

Comment: Would the limits of the integral of the _cdf_ be from $0$ to $x$?

Comment: I would prefer equal signs, rather than arrows, for your second-to-last comment [and mention something about positivity to avoid flipping inequalities and/or dividing by zero].  How would you evaluate $P[X < 1/y]$, given the PDF of $X$? [also, I do not understand your last comment about $x$.  What is $x$?]

Comment: @Michael: I guess I'd mention that $y \neq 0$. As to how I'd evaluate $P(X<y^{-1})$ given the _pdf_ of _X_, that step eludes me. Sorry, I used _x_ as the upper bound (and $0$ as the lower) of the integral of $f_X(x)$ to get $F_X(x)$. Is that the right procedure?

Comment: Given a PDF $f_W(w)$ and an interval $w \in [a,b]$, can you give an expression for $P[W \in [a,b]]$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45666/discussion-between-pizzazzra-and-michael). _Ignore this_.

Comment: @Michael That's the bit I'm struggling with. The expressions for $P$ w.r.t. _pdfs_. (Among other things).

Comment: You integrate a PDF over the desired interval.  $P[W\in [a,b]] = \int_a^b f_W(w)dw$.

Comment: Ahhh, got it! Thanks!

Comment: @Michael I wrote out my solution in the question: does it seem right?

Comment: $\frac{d}{dy}P[Y>y] = \frac{d}{dy} (1-F_Y(y))= -f_Y(y)$.  And you need your $y$ to satisfy $y>0$ for your previous manipulations to be valid.

Comment: Is it possible for a _pdf_ to be negative? Or is the answer basically written as: $-f_Y(y) = \frac{3y^2}{(y+1)^4}$ defined when $1 \geqslant y > 0$?

Comment: No a pdf cannot be negative.